# Can not see an app with name "advertisements" in admin interface

Tags: django

When I add an app with the name `advertisements` (add models, admin + register in `INSTALLED_APPS`) it is not listed in the admin interface (it is very hard to see but it disappears after microseconds).

`models.py`:

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Advertisement(models.Model):
    pass
```

`admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Advertisement

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(Advertisement)
class AdvertisementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

`apps.py`:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AdvertisementsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'advertisements'
```

`settings.py`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    "advertisements",
]
```

Changing an app directory to something like `advertisements2`, app name (in `apps.py`) to `advertisements2` solves the problem.

Why the app with the name 'advertisements' is not listed in the admin interface?" What is the issue with the name "advertisements"?

I tested in many times in completely blank project.

Comment: So what you are asking?

Comment: I am asking: "Why the app with the name 'advertisements' is not listed in the admin interface?" What is the issue?

Comment: Admin interface what do you mean?, `Models` are registered in admin interface to see data itself in admin interface, rather than using different GUI tools for different databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question seemd to be a bit strange for me at the beginning and I was feeling super curious about what is going on. I recreated your code perfectly and I was getting the same result as you. No `advertisemets` app in admin panel. I started a debugger and tracked execution line by line, and everything seemd to be in order. But after some time it occured to me, that it could not be actually django's fault. And it is not! Beware the most intriguing solution to your problem:

**Just disable your adblocker and refresh the site!**

What is most problably the problem (and what was the problem on my site) is that my adblocker blocked the word `advertisement` and all the styles that came with it. So with your adblocker turned on, if you were to inspect a site you would see your `advertisements` app sitting comfortably in your html code:

```
<div class="app-advertisements module">
      <table>
        <caption>
          <a href="/admin/advertisements/" class="section" title="Models in the Advertisements application">Advertisements</a>
        </caption>
        
          <tbody><tr class="model-advertisement">
            
              <th scope="row"><a href="/admin/advertisements/advertisement/">Advertisements</a></th>
```

If you were to remove `app-advertisements` class from `<div class="app-advertisements module">` (again, with the adblocker still turned on) the Advertisement should magically apear in admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `admin.site.register(Advertisement)` instead of the AdminView in `admin.py`. If this line works, you could add the model admin view individually like this:

```
class AdvertisementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Advertisement, AdvertisementAdmin)
```

Comment: No this doesn't work. As I wrote in the question changing the app name solves the issue (there is some strange thing with the name `advertisements`). If you really want to help you can set up a test `startproject` in 2 minutes and test it yourself before answering...