# Certain models not showing up in django 4 admin despite being registered

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using django 4.0.3 and the `restframework`.

I have serval models registered in django admin:

```
@admin.register(models.Drug)
class DrugAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('apl_label', 'name', 'drug_class', 'atc_code', )
    
@admin.register(models.Organism)
class OrganismAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('apl_label', 'long_name', 'short_name', 'genus', 'flagged', 'notes')

....
```

For some reason, some o fthe models are not showing up in the admin view. In this example, Organism shows up, but Drug is hidden. I can go to `http://localhost:8000/admin/api/drug/` and access this admin page, but it is not listed under `http://localhost:8000/admin/`. There is no error message either. I did run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Permissions are only set globally in `settings.py`:

```
...
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
],
```

It is always the same models not showing up. I tried deleting the database and creating everything from scratch. No luck. Why does Django decide to not show certain models?

[image]

But when I go to `http://localhost:8000/admin/api/organism/` all models show up in the side bar:

[image]

I tried registering the admin page with `admin.site.register(Drug)`, but that did not change anything.

Comment: Did you add the app which contains the admin.py file to your `INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Yes, there is just one app. All the models belong to that one.

Comment: @Soren Try to move/recreate your `admin.py` file and to clear the cache of your IDE (maybe the problem is arisen from it). You can also try to recreate the whole project from scratch

Comment: Do you have any ad blockers running in your browser. Based on the keywords that are "disappearing", it is possible they are interfering. An easy way to check would be to inspect the generated source code to see whether the links are in fact being rendered by Django (or try in a different browser with no ad blockers installed). Someone else had [exactly this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71714053/3955830) recently.

Answer (score 0):

If this solves your problem you can use this. Or you can check this to understand is the problem because of your `admin.py` or not.

This will work properly:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (
    Drug,
    Organism,
    )

admin.site.register(Drug)
admin.site.register(Organism)
```

Answer (score 0):

That should not happen. Your code seems perfectly fine to me. Make sure your top imports contain the following lines too:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models
```

If your models don't have any extra customization like custom fieldsets and/or custom section-titles, you can try using the regular old admin.site.register(models.modelname). Maybe the decorator is malfunctioning for you for some reason, though I have never seen that happen before.